# MySQL : Automation of the re-execution of Queries from History

Tags: php, mysql, shell, batch-file, testing

I have a simple MySQL database and I need to get the  queries which have been already executed , and develop a script php - shell which ***may re-execute those queries*** whatever i want : so

1. ***First Step :***

i started by transfer my queries to a log file  by doing this configuration within phpmyadmin

- `SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE"; which is set by default.`
- `SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "/path/to/your/logfile.log";`
- `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`

  2.***Second Step :***

i need to automate the re-execution of those queries which are in my log file after sorting them with date (for example : re-execute the queries of "today") .

I have had sugesstions like scripts php or shell 
but i need to have a script which may be usefull within windows and linux ***, so that i'm looking for a tool which may do that ,***

> *any suggestions ?*

Comment: "Automatisate"... interesting word; I think you mean "automate"... ;-) Anyway, your question is off-topic here since StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You need to try in on your own and show your efforts, then we are glad to be of service. Please read these help topics: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for the advices , for the interesting word , thanks it may create the buzz